# How can I compile a Go program?

Tags: go

I got **Go** to compile:

```
0 known bugs; 0 unexpected bugs
```

and typed in the "hello world":

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
  fmt.Printf("Hello, 世界\n")
}
```

Then I tried to compile it, but it wouldn't go:

```
$ 8c gotest2
gotest2:1 not a function
gotest2:1 syntax error, last name: main
```

This is going on on Ubuntu Linux on Pentium. Go installed and passed its tests. So where did I go wrong? Can someone tell me where to go from here?

I also tried [this program](http://golang.org/doc/go_tutorial.html#tmp%5F32):

```
package main

import fmt "fmt"  // Package implementing formatted I/O.


func main() {
    fmt.Printf("Hello, world; or Καλημέρα κόσμε; or こんにちは 世界\n");
}
```

But this was also no go <sub>(must stop making go puns)</sub>:

```
$ 8c gotest3.go
gotest3.go:1 not a function
gotest3.go:1 syntax error, last name: main
```

Comment: have you tried it without the kanji?

Comment: @barkmadley: I tried that, and got the same error message again.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're using 8c, which is the c compiler. 8g will compile go, and 8l will link.

Comment: 8c is the plan-9 c compiler which comes with go, it is seperate from you're systems c compiler

Comment: In regards to the other answers, a semicolon is optional at the end of a block (supposedly for one-liners, although it seems a poor idea to me) and the import fmt "fmt" renames a namespace, so you can use e.g. import goformat "fmt" and then call goformat.Print()

Answer (score 42):

For Go 1.0+ the correct build command is now: `go build`

Answer (score 3):

(Update for Go1.0.x)

The  section "[Compile packages and dependencies](http://golang.org/cmd/go/#Compile_packages_and_dependencies)" now list go build as the way to compile in go.
You still call `8g` behind the scene, and the parameters you could pass to `8g` are now passed with `-gcflags`.

```
-gcflags 'arg list'
```

> arguments to pass on each 5g, 6g, or 8g compiler invocation

Answer (score 0):

use go run  to run the go program. Here is the output.

$ cat testgo.go

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("Hello, 世界\n")
}
```

`$go run testgo.go`

```
Hello, 世界
```

Answer (score 0):

To compile Go code, use the following commands:

```
go tool compile gotest3.go # To create an object file.
go tool link -o gotest3 gotest3.o # To compile from the object file.
chmod +x gotest3 # To apply executable flag.
./gotest3 # To run the binary.
```